# Use worker_threads in combination with node (v11.15.0), webpack and typescript -> module not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm writting a NodeJS application where I want to use worker_threads to get rid of a blocking I/O call `_mfrc522.findCard()` by a third party module (`mfrc522-rpi`) which delays the request handling of a WebApi in the same application.

When I try to reference the `worker_threads` module in my TypeScript file I get the following WebPack error message:

`const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');`

```
ERROR in ./core/command-processing/rfid-command-processor.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/home/pi/leabox/src/core/command-processing'
 @ ./core/command-processing/rfid-command-processor.ts 11:19-44
 @ ./core/leabox-controller.ts
 @ ./index.ts
```

But I'm able to execute the following command directly:

`node -e "require('worker_threads'); console.log('success');`

Output:
 `success`

- Node version: 11.15.0
- WebPack version: 4.41.2
- TypeScript version: 3.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating experimental worker support for node.js via the command line before starting the application solved the issue for me:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-worker
```

Please check this [thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16611) for further information.